# BigQuery python client dropping some rows using Streaming API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-python

I have around a million data items being inserted into BigQuery using streaming API (BigQuery Python Client's `insert_row` function), but there's some data loss, ~10,000 data items are lost while inserting. Is there a chance BigQuery might be dropping some of the data? Since there aren't any insertion errors (or any errors whatsoever for that matter).

Comment: If BigQuery had a problem with dropping data, everybody would be screaming and nobody would use the product. You have a problem with your code / processes. However, you did not include anything in your question to help you with.

Comment: please report with more specifics on the BigQuery issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559654

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to file a [private Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#search_for_or_create_bugs_and_feature_requests_by_producthttps://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#search_for_or_create_bugs_and_feature_requests_by_product) in order for the BigQuery Engineers to look into this. Make sure to provide affected project, the source of the data, the code that you're using to stream into BigQuery along with the client library version.